# TextEditingController value not getting saved to a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` called `woodsArray`.

I require to add three parameters named length, breadth, and area inside this list. For this, I am using a `ListView.builder` and three lists of `TextEditingController`. MY requirement is such that the area should be based on length and breadth. Though it is rendering correctly, but it is not getting added to `woodsArray`.

This is what I have done so far.

```
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> woodsArray = [];
  List<TextEditingController> woodlengthControllers = [];
  List<TextEditingController> woodbreadthControllers = [];
  List<TextEditingController> woodAreaControllers = [];
```

In the `ListView.builder` ,

```
 ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: woodsArray.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                woodlengthControllers.add(
                  TextEditingController(text: ''),
                );
                woodbreadthControllers.add(TextEditingController(text: ''));
                woodAreaControllers.add(TextEditingController(text: ''));
                ///// AREA CALCULATION /////
                    if (woodlengthControllers[index].text != '' &&
                    woodbreadthControllers[index].text != '') {
                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                    setState(() {
                      woodAreaControllers[index].text =
                          ((num.tryParse(woodlengthControllers[index].text))! *
                                  (num.tryParse(
                                      woodbreadthControllers[index].text))! *
                                  0.00001111)
                              .toStringAsFixed(2);
                    });
                  });
                },
               //////////////////////////
               return Row(
                 children:[
                     SizedBox(
                            width: 110,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: woodlengthControllers[index],
                              style: formPrimaryTextStyle(context),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelStyle: formPrimaryTextStyle(context),
                              ),
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                woodsArray[index]['wood_length'] =
                                    woodlengthControllers[index].text;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 110,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: woodbreadthControllers[index],
                              style: formPrimaryTextStyle(context),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelStyle: formPrimaryTextStyle(context),
                              ),
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                woodsArray[index]['wood_breadth'] =
                                    woodbreadthControllers[index].text;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                           SizedBox(
                            width: 110,
                            child: TextFormField(
                              controller: woodAreaControllers[index],
                              style: formPrimaryTextStyle(context),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                                labelStyle: formPrimaryTextStyle(context),
                              ),
                              onChanged: (val) {
                                woodsArray[index]['wood_area'] =
                                    woodAreaControllers[index].text;
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                      ],
                 );  
             },
           ),
```

Up to this point, the area gets rendered correctly in the `ListView`. But when i try to print the `woodsArray`, it only shows the length and the breadth which i defined , not the area which was getting calculated automatically based on the length and breadth controller values. Consider this for example.

`woodsArray=[{'wood_length':1200, 'wood_breadth':300}]` (No 'wood_area')

What am i doing wrong? Can someone suggest me something I should do differently?

Comment: You are only setting the 'wood_area' when you manually type something in the area textfield

Comment: Thanks mate. I can't believe that I overlooked this.

Comment: But there's several other things wrong with your code. Calculating the area in the builder is not the right way to do it because it creates an infinite loop because it keeps calling setState. Also, adding new controllers everytime it comes in the builder is not right because it will make the list of controllers keep growing. Furthermore I would suggest to make a separate class that represents a wood item instead of having that map.

Answer (score 1):

I've reworked your code in a way that I think is much better. Try out this full working example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(home: MainPage()));
}

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  List<Wood> woodsArray = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: woodsArray.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          final Wood wood = woodsArray[index];
          return Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                width: 110,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: wood.lengthController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    wood.calculateArea();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 110,
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: wood.breadthController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    wood.calculateArea();
                  },
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 110,
                child: TextFormField(
                  enabled: false,
                  controller: wood.areaController,
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => setState(
          () {
            print(woodsArray);
            woodsArray.add(Wood('1200', '300'));
          },
        ),
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Wood {
  TextEditingController lengthController;
  TextEditingController breadthController;
  TextEditingController areaController = TextEditingController();

  Wood(String length, String breadth)
      : lengthController = TextEditingController(text: length),
        breadthController = TextEditingController(text: breadth) {
    calculateArea();
  }

  void calculateArea() {
    final l = num.tryParse(length);
    final b = num.tryParse(breadth);
    if (l != null && b != null) {
      areaController.text = (l * b * 0.0001111).toStringAsFixed(2);
    }
  }

  String get length => lengthController.text;

  String get breadth => breadthController.text;

  String get area => areaController.text;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Wood(length: $length, breadth: $breadth, area: $area';
}
```

Note that I had to leave out the calls to `formPrimaryTextStyle` because I didn't know the implementation, so you could add that in again. Pressing the + will add a new Wood item and also print the current list of wood. I hope it gives you insight to better software development.